# Docker Permission error while not using root

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When i create dockerfile using this way I'll run into error

```
    FROM node:18.12.1-alpine3.17
    RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
    USER app 
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY package*.json .
    COPY . .
    RUN npm install
    ENV API_URL=http://api.myapp.com/
    EXPOSE 3000
    CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

This is the error i get...

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\react-docker>docker build -t react-app .
[+] Building 17.5s (10/10) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 264B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18.12.1-alpine3.17                                         0.5s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 4.74kB                                                                                0.0s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:18.12.1 - 0.0s
 => CACHED [2/6] RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [3/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                      0.0s
 => [4/6] COPY package*.json .                                                                                     0.1s
 => [5/6] COPY . .                                                                                                 0.0s
 => ERROR [6/6] RUN npm install                                                                                   16.8s
------
 > [6/6] RUN npm install:
#10 13.03 npm notice
#10 13.03 npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.2 -> 9.4.2
#10 13.03 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.4.2>
#10 13.03 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.4.2` to update!
#10 13.03 npm notice
#10 13.03 npm ERR! code EACCES
#10 13.03 npm ERR! syscall open
#10 13.03 npm ERR! path /app/package-lock.json
#10 13.03 npm ERR! errno -13
#10 13.03 npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/package-lock.json'
#10 13.03 npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/package-lock.json'] {
#10 13.03 npm ERR!   errno: -13,
#10 13.03 npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
#10 13.03 npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
#10 13.03 npm ERR!   path: '/app/package-lock.json'
#10 13.03 npm ERR! }
#10 13.03 npm ERR!
#10 13.03 npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
#10 13.03 npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
#10 13.03 npm ERR!
#10 13.03 npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
#10 13.03 npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
#10 13.03 npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
#10 13.03
#10 13.03 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#10 13.03 npm ERR!     /home/app/.npm/_logs/2023-02-10T01_12_33_542Z-debug-0.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install]: exit code: 243
```

Already saw other person like him: https://forum.codewithmosh.com/t/permission-issues-in-my-dockerfile/17216

running into same error but unfortunately no suggestion how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do two things here.

The first is to run [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ci) instead of `npm install`.  This will install the exact set of things listed in the `package-lock.json`, and never try to modify it.  That should avoid the problem where `npm` can't write the lock file.

The second change is to move the `USER app` line to the end of the Dockerfile.  Run the entire build sequence as root.  Your application, its source code, and the `node_modules` directory will all be owned by root; but they will also all be world-readable.  Your build will run successfully, but when you start the container, it won't have write permission to alter its own source code, libraries, or static assets.  That's generally a more secure setup and won't usually impact your application at all.